# SHA-1 value of url is changing very frequently, which affects the Cordova apps secure connection

Tags: cordova, ssl, sha1

SHA 1 value is using in our Cordova app for secure connection (SSL/TLS). but for one of the third party url its SHA1 values is keep on changing frequently. We are using a ssl-checker Cordova plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-sslcertificatechecker) for validating the SHA value. is there any alternative solution we need to follow ?

Comment: Do I understand this correctly that you do certificate pinning but then certificates out of your control change too often? If this is the problem then you should ask yourself, why do you certificate pinning in the first place. Certificate pinning makes sense against certificates you control but not against certificates you don't control and which can change all the time. Either don't use a third party in the first place. Or use the standard and more scalable  way of validating certificates - by trusting specific (and long-lived) CA and validating the chain from certificate to CA.

Comment: Yeah. i agree that. so what should be the alternative one.. is it public key pinning or certificates itself pin with the app ?

Comment: to cite myself: *"... use the standard and more scalable way of validating certificates - by trusting specific (and long-lived) CA and validating the chain from certificate to CA."*. In other words: simply don't do anything special but use the certificate validation build into the OS.